# why does this code work with just an individual image URL?

Tags: python, http, sockets, https, connection

I have this little code from the book "python for every body" and it works completely fine with the given image URL.
The issue is when I change the URL in the socket command , the connection blows up and return data like this:

494 494
Header length 176
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 04 May 2022 21:34:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 314
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

the second URL that doesn't work is:
http://thewowstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/cat1.jpg

```
import socket
import time

HOST = 'data.pr4e.org'
PORT = 80

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect((HOST, PORT))
mysock.sendall(b'GET http://data.pr4e.org/cover3.jpg HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n')
count = 0
picture = b""

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(5120)
    if len(data) < 1: break
    time.sleep(0.25)
    count = count + len(data)
    print(len(data), count)
    picture = picture + data

mysock.close()

# Look for the end of the header (2 CRLF)

pos = picture.find(b"\r\n\r\n")
print('Header length', pos)
print(picture[:pos].decode())

# Skip past the header and save the picture data

picture = picture[pos+4:]
fhand = open("stuff.jpg", "wb")
fhand.write(picture)
fhand.close()
```

Comment: some servers may have more complex system to detect spamers and hackers and it may need other headers after `GET` to recognize browser and send correct data.

Comment: BTW: second link doesn't send image but it redirects to page with `www.` at the beginning.

Comment: did you set `HOST = "thewowstyle.com"` when you tested second link?

Comment: page `http://thewowstyle.com` uses server `CloudFlare` which has very complex system to detect bots/scripts - it may even use `JavaScript` to detect real browser but your script can't run JavaScript.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.